# Adding Moving obstacle

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I integrate the [animated box from gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=animated_box) with ROS?

It is bit unclear on how to launch it along with my Robot.

Thanks !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313333/adding-moving-obstacle/) by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 224 on 2019-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

The best bet for adding moving obstacles will be to use the message

```
gazebo/set_model_state
```

Incase, if you need a much more elaborate code for moving obstacles, Checkout this [turtlebot_3_machine_learning_moving_obstacles](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_machine_learning/blob/master/turtlebot3_dqn/nodes/moving_obstacle)

Thanks !

---

Originally posted by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) with karma: 224 on 2019-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0